# How do I iterate array hash to make a table?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have this hash that holds and array that contains hash:

```
{ 
 "Company1" => [
   { "name" => "test1",   "count" => 2},
   { "name" => "test123", "count" => 3}
 ],
 "Company2" => [
   { "name" => "test33",  "count" => 2},
   { "name" => "test453", "count" => 3},
   { "name" => "test342", "count" => 2},
   { "name" => "test90",  "count" =>3}
 ]
}
```

I want to iterate it so i can make the format to print it out in the table format. The table format is like this probably:

```
Company  | Name   |   Count
Company1
          test1       2
          test123     3
Company2
          test33      2
          test453     3
          test342     2
          test90      3
```

So how do I iterate the ruby hash that contains an array of hash.

Comment: Your sentence in the question is not completed. Not clear what you are writing.

Comment: Your hash is invalid.

Comment: @sawa it is a valid RUBY hash, you could copy and paste it and try on your own

Comment: Don't try to make a false impression. It **became** a valid hash after jlhonora's edit two days ago.

Comment: @sawa okay, it was a typo, sorry for that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
hash.each do |company, elements|
  puts "#{company}\t\t"
  elements.each do |v|
    puts "\t#{v['name']}\t#{v['count']}"
  end
end
```